# How to use data from $http.get after page load in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I can't figure out how to execute a function in Vue.js after an `$http.get` request has finished. In the following example I want to automatically select an element of `foobar` right after page load, but this works only when the alert is there.

```
new Vue({

    el: '#foo',

    data: {
        foobar: [],
        foobar_selected: []
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.fetchFoobar();
        alert('silly');
        this.selectFoobar(2);
    },

    methods: {
        fetchFoobar: function () {
            this.$http.get('foobar_to_fetch', function (foobar_fetched) {
                this.foobar = foobar_fetched;
            })
        },
        selectFoobar: function (index) {
            this.foobar_selected.push(this.foobar[index]);
        }
    }

});
```

-

```
<div id="foo">

    <h2>Foobars</h2>
    <table>
        <tr v-repeat="foobar">
            <td>{{ id }}</td>
            <td>{{ name }}</td>
            <td><button v-on="click: selectFoobar($index)">select</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h2>Selected Foobars</h2>
    <table>
        <tr v-repeat="foobar_selected">
            <td>{{ id }}</td>
            <td>{{ name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

It says here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource that <strike>the third argument</strike> of `get` is `success`, but I don't understand how I am supposed to use it in this case. At least this works:

```
this.$http.get('foobar_to_fetch', function (foobar_fetched) {
    this.foobar = foobar_fetched;
}, alert('useless'));
```

But this does not:

```
this.$http.get('foobar_to_fetch', function (foobar_fetched) {
    this.foobar = foobar_fetched;
}, this.selectFoobar(2));
```

What is the correct way to do this in Vue.js?

I am using Vue 0.11.10 and Vue-resource 0.1.16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get` has the following signature:

```
get(url, [data], [success], [options])
```

`data` is in square brackets, which means that parameter is optional. Since `data` is defined as:

> Object|string - Data to be sent as the request message data

You are *not* passing in an object/string as the second parameter to the function. That means that **the second argument you are passing in is interpreted as the success callback function!** It doesn't have to be the third argument!

If you do something like this:

```
this.$http.get('foobar_to_fetch', function(data, status, request) {
  this.foobar = data;
  this.selectFoobar(2);
});
```

It should theoretically work. This is just a guess though based on my glance at the Vue documentation that you linked in your question.

Comment: Thank you. `status` and `request` are not even necesseary. The `this.selectFoobar(2)` just has to be inside the `get` function and not after it. Can't believe I had not tried that...

Comment: @mate2code Yep they may not be necessary. I was just trying to convey that the function *is* the success callback. Also even if it wasn't, you would have to wrap the command in a function like this: `function() { this.selectFoobar(2) }` so the function you're passing it to could execute that code *at a later time*. That's essentially what callbacks are all about; wrapping up code in functions so you can pass them to other functions that will execute your functions when its the right time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. "**The function _is_ the success callback.** That is what I missed, because I thought in terms of "the n-th argument of `get(url, [data], [success], [options])`".